# Iterating over Shopware Array and trying to get the key not working

Tags: twig, shopware

Hey iam currently trying to get the description of the first menu navigation in Shopware 6.
For that i use the array page.header.navigation.active.breadcrumb and use its key in page.header.navigation.tree[key].description, but my key value is empty.
Thats happening due to the key beeing empty for no reason.

Heres my Code:

```
{% sw_extends "@Storefront/storefront/section/cms-section-sidebar.html.twig" %}

{% set topMenu = null %}
{% for key, value in page.header.navigation.active.breadcrumb %}
    {% if loop.index == 2 %}
        {% set topMenu = value %}
        {# {% set topMenuDescription = page.header.navigation.tree[key].category.description %} #}
        {% set topMenuDescription = key %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% set currentMenu = page.header.navigation.active.breadcrumb | last %}
{# {% set currentMenu = page.header.navigation.active.name %} #}
{# {% set topMenuDescription = page.header.navigation.active.description %} #}
{# {% if ! topMenuDescription %}
    {% set topMenuDescription = page.header.navigation.active.description %}
{% endif %} #}

{% block section_main_content_block %}
    <div class="category-top">
        <div class="category-banner">
            <img src="/media/6a/fd/8b/1632946677/listing-banner.jpg">
            <div class="category-banner-headlines">
                {% if (currentMenu != topMenu) %}
                    <h3>{{ topMenu }}<h3>
                    <h2>{{ currentMenu }}<h2>
                {% else %}
                    <h2 class="sameMenu">{{ currentMenu }}<h2>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="category-description">
            <h1>{{ currentMenu }}</h1>
            {{ topMenuDescription | trans | raw }}
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

Also here is the structure of the key i want to get:
[key-i-want-to-get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACdXD.png)

And heres the description i want to get:
[description-i-want-to-get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q55KY.png)

Sidenote: The description in my example is empty, since i do the showcase in a seperate testing area, where i havent set a description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `topMenuDescription` is empty is because the variable only exist inside the scope of the `{% for %}`-loop you've created. Outside this loop the variable doesn't exist.

In order to solve this issue you need to alter the scope of `topMenuDescription` by defining the variable outside the `{% for %}`-loop

```html
{% set topMenuDescription = null %}
{% for key, value in page.header.navigation.active.breadcrumb %}
    {% if loop.index == 2 %}
        {% set topMenu = value %}
        {# {% set topMenuDescription = page.header.navigation.tree[key].category.description %} #}
        {% set topMenuDescription = key %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

*sidenote*

You really should enable twig's debug whilst developing as your current snippet would throw a `RuntimeError` explaining the variable does not exist.

Comment: Oh i didn't knew about that, since iam kinda new in SW6 and twig.
That works, thanks a lot :)

Also how would i enable the twig debugger?
Is it the same as setting .env from prod to dev?

Comment: [seems so](https://docs.shopware.com/en/en/shopware-6-en/tutorials-and-faq/debugging#activate-the-debug-or-developer-mode)